# Is the following construction a measure?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure

Please excuse my informality, but I am currently working on the intuition behind the idea.

Suppose two parameters are given:

1. An event $E$ composed of basic events, like union and intersection of basic events.
2. A vector of probabilities $\overline{p}$ are given for the basic events.

Suppose, I have a construction that evaluates the probability of the composed event on the basis of the probabilities of the basic events and does some further math (not relevant here), such that the result $r$ of the process is a value in $[0,1]$.

In the last step, I compute the value $f(E,\overline{p})=1-r$.

Here is my question: Does it make sense to say that $f$ is a measure? The function does assign each $E$ and $\overline{p}$ a value. Non-negativity can be easily shown. But what about the empty set property and the additivity?

What would be the $\Sigma$-algebra here, what would be the other relevant parameters of a measure?

Would be really great, if you could help me out here.